# How to get key of Chrome Console Request payload, if there is only a value?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, http, python-requests

I want to send a post request to a website and analyzed it via Chrome Console. The payload seems to only show a value, but no key, like this:

[image: request payload without key]

How would I send a post request, for example in python, if I don't know the key?

```
import requests
key = "????"
value = 'foobar'
site_url = "https://website123.com/api"
    response = requests.post(site_url, data={
        key : value
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `value=foobar`, or whatever the key seems to be (could be `v` as well).

Click on View Source and you will be able to see the raw payload. Use that.